# SSRS Indicator Color start and end Expression

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, expression, indicator

I have 3 Different conditions which should show up in different colors such as red, yellow and green. There is always a >= , <= , = operator in between of the columns Price and AVG(Price).Since i dont really have start and end Point i dont have clue how to use the Expression.

```
=IIf(Fields!Price.Value >= AVG(Fields!Price.Value),"Green","Yellow")
```

How do i use the indicator start and end Expressions? 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rV2Ew.png)

Answer (score 0):

Use a nested IIf

```
=IIf(Fields!Price.Value >= AVG(Fields!Price.Value),"Green",
     IIf(Fields!Price.Value >= AVG(Fields!Price.Value2),"Red","Yellow"))
```

Comment: Thank you! I found another way through your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
=IIF(SUM(Fields!Store_Gesamtumsatz.Value)<AVG(Fields!Store_Gesamtumsatz.Value),"RED",IIF(SUM(FIELDS!Store_Gesamtumsatz.Value)=AVG(Fields!Store_Gesamtumsatz.Value),"YELLOW",IIF(SUM(Fields!Store_Gesamtumsatz.Value)>AVG(Fields!Store_Gesamtumsatz.Value),"GREEN",NOTHING)))
```